# PHP get_file_content, content different on multiple hosts

Tags: php, configuration

I have a issue where I have identical code on different hosting providers. They are both meant to collect data from Linnworks API.

The issue had been on the new host, allow_url_fopen was set to OFF.  Once I fixed this I started getting data.

However, there is a huge difference in the amount of data I get, the old host I get lots, but the new host I get very little, even with identical code.

I asked the support of the new host, who pointed me to allow_url_fopen, and they said compare the two phpinfo() from both hosting, because it's a php configuration problem.

Looking at both, there are many differences, what is the correct part of the PHPINFO() to look at to see if there are limits to the amount of data get_file_contents allows me to collect ?

**UPDATE**

This is what the New host gives:

```
Array ( [Id] => 369fe666-b738-490d-8621-02717ee268d1 [SKU] => WC-MGR62ZM/A [Title] => Genuine Apple iPhone 6 Leather Case Black Leather [Price] => 29.99 [Images] => [Extend] => [Description] => )
```

This is what the old host gives, as an example:

```
Array ( [Id] => 369fe666-b738-490d-8621-02717ee268d1 [SKU] => WC-MGR62ZM/A [Title] => Genuine Apple iPhone 6 Leather Case Black Leather [Price] => 29.99 [Images] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [pkRowId] => df430ba3-bd61-46ab-88e2-659801432c45 [Source] => http://images.linnlive.com/b437b033b085aa0cc7e48e8e31f766d1/tumbnail_df430ba3-bd61-46ab-88e2-659801432c45.jpg [IsMain] => [StockItemId] => 369fe666-b738-490d-8621-02717ee268d1 ) [1] => Array ( [pkRowId] => afa351a2-fbd9-4bd4-8c22-99f47a82af42 [Source] => http://images.linnlive.com/b437b033b085aa0cc7e48e8e31f766d1/tumbnail_afa351a2-fbd9-4bd4-8c22-99f47a82af42.jpg [IsMain] => [StockItemId] => 369fe666-b738-490d-8621-02717ee268d1 ) [2] => Array ( [pkRowId] => 62e0b4ab-230d-457c-9fac-c8cf4f0877ba [Source] => http://images.linnlive.com/b437b033b085aa0cc7e48e8e31f766d1/tumbnail_62e0b4ab-230d-457c-9fac-c8cf4f0877ba.jpg [IsMain] => [StockItemId] => 369fe666-b738-490d-8621-02717ee268d1 ) ) [Extend] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [pkRowId] => 41e84165-5993-42e9-8a99-04e924e47b74 [fkStockItemId] => 369fe666-b738-490d-8621-02717ee268d1 [ProperyName] => Type [PropertyValue] => Fitted Case/Skin [PropertyType] => Attribute )
```

Something that may be relevant is it is making multiple get_file_content calls to collect all this data.

**SECOND UPDATE**

The issue does seem to be that the new server prevents me from making multiple get_file_content calls.  Going over the PHPINFO() from each, and making changes has made no positive effect so far.  But as it makes the first call fine, the second call comes back blank, so no errors, much like before when allow_url_fopen was off ?

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Is the content different, or is it just cut off in the middle? I don't think there are any limits to how much data `file_get_contents` can download. Either it's allowed or it isn't, nothing in between.

Comment: Same content, but cut off near the very start, rather than the middle ?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628801/is-there-a-limit-on-php-file-get-contents

Comment: I had seen that, the memory limit on both are set to 128M, but as it's a different server I changed it on the new host to 512M, and post_max_size from 8M to 100M as old host.  But still no joy :(

Comment: What is the length it stops at? Does the problem only happen with this file?

Comment: I have added some extra information to give you an idea.  Note also it is making multiple calls to gather the data.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` returns a string, not an array. How are you getting that array? Is it returning JSON? If you can successfully convert it to an array with `json_decode()`, then it can't be cut off in the middle. It looks like the server may be filtering the response somehow.

Comment: Yes, based on trouble shooting it seems that because the data is JSON and large, the chunk size is too large, and so the server is ignoring it.  This is because on the old host, memcache module is installed, but on the new host, it is not, and they will not install it.  Need to upgradge hosting.